# Update parent id Hierarchy - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column with the account IDs and I need to create a hierarchy scheme. So I created a column to add the parent account IDs, but I do not know how to update dynamically.

I updated some records manually to find out how it would look, how could I make a script to update the other almost 2,000 lines?

[image]

Comment: How do you select records to be updated, by 'Account' or by 'AccountParent'?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [RECURSIVE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) query for this job:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE accounts(account varchar(10), account_parent varchar(10), updated_field int);
> INSERT INTO accounts VALUES
> ('10000', NULL, 0),
> ('10001','10000', 0),
> ('10002','10001', 0),
> ('10003','10002', 0),
> ('10004','10003', 0),
> ('10005','10004', 0),
> ('10006','10005', 0),
> ('10007', NULL, 0),
> ('10008', NULL, 0),
> ('10009', NULL, 0),
> ('10010', NULL, 0),
> ('10011', NULL, 0);
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> ;WITH tree AS
> (
>     SELECT c1.account, c1.account_parent, Level = 1
>     FROM dbo.[accounts] c1
>     WHERE c1.account = '10000'
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT c2.account, c2.account_parent, Level = Level + 1
>     FROM dbo.[accounts] c2 INNER JOIN tree ON tree.account = c2.account_parent
> )
> UPDATE accounts
> SET    updated_field = Level
> FROM   tree
> INNER  JOIN accounts
> ON     accounts.account = tree.account
> OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM accounts;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> account | account_parent | updated_field
> :------ | :------------- | ------------:
> 10000   | null           |             1
> 10001   | 10000          |             2
> 10002   | 10001          |             3
> 10003   | 10002          |             4
> 10004   | 10003          |             5
> 10005   | 10004          |             6
> 10006   | 10005          |             7
> 10007   | null           |             0
> 10008   | null           |             0
> 10009   | null           |             0
> 10010   | null           |             0
> 10011   | null           |             0
> ```

Keep in mind you must set a MAXRECURSION value greater enough to get all updated records.

**Updating records where parent is null**

To update the rest of the records where account_parent is null I've used a CTE function with [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql).

Note the CTE uses `WHERE    account >= '10006'` to flag the last record of the previous tree structure. The following records must have `account_parent = null`

> ```
> WITH upd AS
> (
>     SELECT   account, account_parent,
>              LAG(account) OVER (ORDER BY account) AS prev_account
>     FROM     accounts
>     WHERE    account >= '10006'    -- this is last element of the tree
> )
> UPDATE     acc
> SET        account_parent = upd.prev_account
> FROM       accounts acc
> INNER JOIN upd
> ON         upd.account = acc.account
> WHERE      upd.prev_account IS NOT NULL
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

This is the final result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM accounts;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> account | account_parent | updated_field
> :------ | :------------- | ------------:
> 10000   | null           |             1
> 10001   | 10000          |             2
> 10002   | 10001          |             3
> 10003   | 10002          |             4
> 10004   | 10003          |             5
> 10005   | 10004          |             6
> 10006   | 10005          |             7
> 10007   | 10006          |             0
> 10008   | 10007          |             0
> 10009   | 10008          |             0
> 10010   | 10009          |             0
> 10011   | 10010          |             0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cbe083470ce54de2c387528c1353f324)*

Comment: The script worked, but how can I do to fill null hierarchies?

Comment: @Rafaells with what values?

Comment: In the account_parent column, it has null values after 10005. How could we continue to populate this column with its parent accounts?

Comment: ok, let me prepare an answer, it requires another sentence.